# Find and replace many words with a loop

Tags: php, sql, replace

I have a replace function, since there are many words to replace, I would like a loop to be made and the words to be replaced are extracted from a database table. I tried to write the code but it didn't work.

**BEFORE:**

```
function replaceString ($content){
    $w = str_replace("apple", "banana", $content);
    $w = str_replace("orange", "pear", $content);
    return $w;
}
```

**AFTER:**

```
function replaceString ($content){
    $Fruits = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Fruits ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Fruits))){
        $content = str_replace($row['word'], $row['replace'], $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: What actually happens? Does your query work at all? Is your `$mysqli` database object in scope? Is it correct that each time you call `str_replace` you are calling it with the original `$content`, so forgetting all the previous replacements? I think that `if()` clause isn't needed either - just use the `while()` loop.

Comment: What kind of construct is `if(while())` supposed to be? A while loop does not have a "return value". That `if` has no place being there, remove it and _just_ do the loop.

Comment: The "BEFORE" version does not work because at the second line of the function you need to replace $w and not $content: $w = str_replace("orange", "pear", $w);

Comment: Actually in the code there was no "if" I added it here by mistake, I removed it so as not to confuse. In any case, the code does not work equally the function does not give errors, I simply do not display the string where the function is used, in practice it returns null output.

Comment: You have to wrap keys with quotes, otherwise PHP will assume these are constants and throw a warning `Use of undefined constant word - assumed 'word'`. You should really enable all errors whilst in development. `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` This way you'd see PHP is throwing a warning

Comment: what are ``word`` and ``replace`` constants doing?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What does "didn't work" mean? Also, how is this question related to SQL itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass $mysql into your function:

```
<?php

function replaceString ($mysqli, $content){
    $Fruits = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Fruits ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Fruits)) {
        $content = str_replace($row['word'], $row['replace'], $content);
    }
    return $content;
}

$string = 'An apple better then sugar, but orange not';


echo replaceString($mysqli, $string);
```

after this change code works.
[PHP mysqli online here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=d6daa4f740db3c832dc86627c255b799&sqlses=ea4871001f3a878c3174288be4f3817f&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

**Result**:

```
An banana better then sugar, but pear not
```

also you can to know str_replace can use arrays as parameters, so you can avoid loop:

```
function replaceString ($mysqli, $content){
    $fruits = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Fruits ORDER BY id DESC");
    
    $rows = $fruits->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
    return str_replace(array_column($rows, 'word'), array_column($rows, 'replace'), $content);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, where is `$mysqli` declared ?
Then in your function,

```
   $w = str_replace($row[word], $row[replace], $content);
```

should be replaced by

```
   $content = str_replace($row[word], $row[replace], $content);
```

the variable `$w` is of no use since there's nothing else you do with `$content`, just overwrite it. Moreover, it prevents your function from working fine, as you replace only in `$content` and not `$w` that you return.

Comment: I did but it still doesn't work. When I declare this function on a string replaceString($content) this is no longer displayed. As if the function had an error, if instead I remove the loop for extracting data from the database, it works perfectly.

Comment: have you seen @Darkbee comment ? I hadn't noticed but word and replace should be quoted, I guess ?

Comment: `$row[word]` should throw obvious syntax errors, unless you defined the constants `word` or `replace` anywhere

Comment: @NicoHaase I withdrawed my comment on this answer. It's seems `PHP<8` will only throw a notice, but interpret the correct index - [demo](https://3v4l.org/upuYr)